# How to use condition for all children in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have these classes:

```
public class product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Store Store { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Color> Colors { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public ICollection<product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this list :

```
  List<Store> Stores = new List<Store>
        {
            new Store { Id = 1, Name = "Lilo", City = "Teh",
                        Products = new List<product> 
                          {
                             new product 
                                 { Id = 1, Title = "Asus",
                                   Colors = new List<Color> {
                                        new Color { Id = 1, Name = "Blue"},
                                        new Color { Id = 2, Name = "Orange"}
                                    }
                                 },
                             new product 
                                 { Id = 2, Title = "Dell",
                                   Colors = new List<Color> {
                                        new Color { Id = 1, Name = "Yellow"},
                                        new Color { Id = 2, Name = "Orange"},
                                        new Color { Id = 3, Name = "Red"}
                                    }
                                 }
                }
            },
            new Store{Id=2,Name="filo",City="san",
                Products=new List<product> 
                {
                    new product{Id=3,Title="Asus",
                Colors=new List<Color>{
                    new Color{Id=1,Name="Blue"},
                    new Color{Id=2,Name="Orange"}
                }
            },
            new product{Id=4,Title="Dell",
                Colors=new List<Color>{
                    new Color{Id=1,Name="Yellow"},
                    new Color{Id=2,Name="Lime"},
                    new Color{Id=3,Name="Red"}
                }
            }
                }
            }
        };
```

I want to select all stores where Name ="Lilo" and products names is "Dell " and Color="Blue". I want do this in Entity Framework, not Linq.

I use this code but it doesn't work :

```
var test = Stores.Where(s => s.Name = "lilo" && s.Products.Where(p => p.Title == "Dell").FirstOrDefault().Title == "Dell" && s.Products.Where(c => c.Colors.Where(ct => ct.Name == "Blue").FirstOrDefault().Name = "Blue")).ToList();
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: What do you mean by `by Entity Framework`? you mean using `Entity SQL`? LinqToEntity is the most suitable tool (avoid error prone) and most commonly used in EF, not sure why you don't want to use LINQ (your code even uses LINQ - is it used to express what you want?)

Comment: You want all Stores, so from your data, what you want should be expressed like this All stores having  ***any*** products named "Dell" and these products should have at least one having color "Blue". So the query can be like this `Stores.Where(s => s.Name == "lilo" && s.Products.Any(p => p.Title == "Dell" && p.Colors.Any(c => c.Color.Name == "Blue"))).ToList()`

Comment: I want LinqToEntity by Method syntax .

Comment: Also consider using `ToLower` for safe comparing against string (missing in my query above).

Comment: @Hopeless Thanks Its work .

Comment: @PsarTak Pease Check Below Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this By Method Syntax :

```
var stlist = Stores.Where(s => s.Name.ToLower() == "lilo" && s.Products.Where(p => p.Colors.Any(c=>c.Name=="Blue") && p.Title == "Dell").FirstOrDefault().Title == "Dell").ToList();
```

Updated :
And   [Hopeless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/733163/hopeless)'s Answers is (best answers):

```
 var lslist2= Stores.Where(s => s.Name == "lilo" && s.Products.Any(p => p.Title == "Dell" && p.Colors.Any(c => c.Color.Name == "Blue"))).ToList();
```

And by Linq :

```
    var test = (from s in Stores
                   from p in s.Products
                   from c in p.Colors
                   where s.Name=="Lilo" && p.Title=="Dell"&& c.Name=="Blue" 
                   select s
                   ).ToList();
```

Comment: try adding a method syntax version, he wants method syntax, you're having an accepted answer soon.

Comment: @Hopeless Your right , ok Change it to Method Syntax or Remove my answer .

Comment: change it to method syntax and notify him about the answer, a question should have an accepted answer. Also the query in my comment was confirmed as working, so you can use that same query in your answer :) (it's hard to be different)